# How do I make TextItem into a center in DynamicForm?

Tags: canvas, user-input, textfield, smartgwt

I am using `smartgwt` and I want to add a `TextItem` to the *Center of a DynamicForm*.

This `DynamicForm enables Resizing`, so the TextItem should always be in it's center. Can anybody help me?

thanks, jogi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FormItem has a lot methods to control its visualization.

Interesting for you should be:

- the [amount of rows that a FormItem takes](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setRowSpan-int-)
- the [number of columns that a FormItem takes](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setColSpan-int-)
- the [horizontal](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setAlign-com.smartgwt.client.types.Alignment-)- and [vertical](https://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/javadoc/com/smartgwt/client/widgets/form/fields/FormItem.html#setVAlign-com.smartgwt.client.types.VerticalAlignment-)-alignment of a Formitem

I.e. If you want to place a FormItem in the center of a DynamicForm-Row you should:

1. set the ColSpan of the FormItem to the amount of columns of the DynamicForm
2. set the Alignment to Alignment.CENTER

Please note that you could use the method DynamicForm.setCellBorder(1) to debug the visualization of your DynamicForm

Comment: I set ColSpan and Alignment, now the textitem is in the center, but always on top and not in die middle of the dynamicform. what i am doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried FormItem.setVAlign(VerticalAlignment.CENTER) also?

Comment: Does your DynamicForm have more than one row?

You could see single cells of the DynamicForm with DynamicForm.setCellBorder(1)

Comment: okay, i see it has one row/cell.....inwith this cell the item is centered. But i want to put the item exactly to the middle of the form. How do i solve that?

Comment: Ok I think I get it.

You have a DynamicForm that consists of a single Cell. Within that cell the FormItem is aligned in a way that you want.

But the single Cell does not fill out the whole DynamicForm?

In that case you should adapt the width and height of your single FormItem, i.e. formItem.setWidth("*") and formItem.setHeight("\*")

Comment: great, thats it! thank you!!!
can you tell me also, how to delete the textitem-border and allow line breaks?

Comment: If you want to allow linebreaks you may consider using a TextAreaItem instead of a TextItem.

The of the formItem is determined by its css class. You could change it by setting the class of the item via formItem.setCellStyle("myCssClass");

Comment: okay next problem :-D when i add css with property border:none, the textitem changes it width and another border is shown? thats strange....

Comment: Then you should compare the css settings of the element before and after assigning a custom css class. You could use tools like firebug to do this.